# Foreign key in of Answers in Question may cause multiple cascade?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

```
create database CodingHelpUz
go

use CodingHelpUz
go

create table Categories (
CategoryID int primary key identity(1,1),
CategoryName nvarchar(max))
go

create table Users(
UserID int primary key identity(1,1),
Email nvarchar(max),
PasswordHash nvarchar(max),
Name nvarchar (max),
Mobile nvarchar (max),
IsAdmin bit default(0))
go

create table Questions(
QuestionID int primary key identity(1,1),
QuestionName nvarchar(max),
QuestionDateAndTime datetime,
UserID int references Users(UserID) on delete cascade,
CategoryID int references Categories(CategoryID) on delete cascade,
VotesCount int,
AnswersCount int,
ViewsCount int)
go

create table Answers(
AnswerID int primary key identity(1,1),
AnswerText nvarchar(max),
AnswerDateAndTime datetime,
UserID int references Users(UserID) on delete cascade,
QuestionID int references Questions(QuestionID) on delete cascade,
VotesCount int)
go

create table Votes(
VoteID int primary key identity (1,1),
UserID int references Users(UserID) on delete cascade,
AnswerID int references Answers(AnswerID) on delete cascade,
VoteValue int)
go

use CodingHelpUz
go

insert into Users values ('akobirmuso@gmail.com','240be518fabd2724ddb6f04eeb1da5967448d7e831c08c8fa822809f74c720a9','Admin','998907172353',1)
go

insert into Users values ('test@gmail.com','ecd71870d1963316a97e3ac3408c9835ad8cf0f3c1bc703527c30265534f75ae','Test','000000000000',0)
go

insert into Categories values('HTML')
go

insert into Categories values('CSS')
go

insert into Categories values('Bootstrap')
go

insert into Categories values('NodeJs')
go

insert into Categories values('JS')
go

insert into Categories values('JQuery')
go

insert into Categories values('PHP')
go

insert into Categories values('C++')
go

insert into Categories values('C#')
go

insert into Categories values('Java')
go

insert into Categories values('Kotlin')
go

insert into Categories values('Python')
go

insert into Categories values('Sql')
go
```

Comment: I saw a nice answer on google 'sql server multiple cascade'.  Triggers and similar constraints just slow things down, but school marks are a different world.  You can constrain and trigger to remove parents with no children or children with no parents, but it takes good, trusted code and keeping the cowboys out of the database, to prevent referential integrity issues.  A daily report is cheaper.

Comment: question is not clear. most of the code snippet it irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Foreign key in of Answers in Question may cause multiple cascade?

Yes.  User>Question>Answer, and User>Answer are two cascade paths.  Just selectively change FKs to ON DELETE NO ACTION, eg

```
create table Answers(
AnswerID int primary key identity(1,1),
AnswerText nvarchar(max),
AnswerDateAndTime datetime,
UserID int references Users(UserID) on delete no action,
QuestionID int references Questions(QuestionID) on delete cascade,
VotesCount int)
go
```

And if an Aswers's UserID is always the same as the Question's UserID, then either remove Answers.UserID, or make the FK on (UserID,QuestionID), which should perhaps the the PK of Users.